# Prime Telescoping Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, closed-form

We know that
$$
\log{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{2n (2n-1)}} \space < \space \sum_{p \space prime} {\frac{1}{p (p-1)}} \space < \space \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{n (n-1)}} = 1
$$
Is there any formula for the mid sum? (constant, value, limit, integral, function)

Comment: Why is the first inequality true?

Comment: I have added the (closed-form) tag, since it seems that this is what you are asking for.

Comment: (1) $ \log{2} < (\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{2.3}+\frac{1}{4.5}=\frac{43}{60}=0.717) $. (2) Any idea about the progression, $ 2n(2n-1)=\{1.2,3.4,5.6,...\} \space\,,\space p(p-1)=\{1.2,2.3,4.5,...\} \space\,,\space n(n-1)=\{1.2,2.3,3.4,...\} $.