# What is this sum? (related to prime numbers)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I was toying around with some prime number related series (trying to generalize some results from a puzzle) and came across this one:

$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p^2+p}$$

Is there any reasonable way to calculate this? If not, can you get some nice bounds on it? (above and below would be nice. I know it lies between $0.3$ and $0.4$, and running it through a program actually tells me it is about $0.33$)

Comment: We can only calculate this sum numerically. With which precision would you be content ?

Comment: FYI, for some bounds on the sum of $\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$, which is similar to your $\frac{1}{p(p+1)}$, please check [Prime Telescoping Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1919325/602049).

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584454/about-sum-p-in-mathbb-p-frac1-operatornamelcm-leftp-p1-right) link

Comment: @  metamorphy,the sum is between $1/6=0.166666666667$ and $0.644934066848$ ,and the sum itself is $0.26149721284$ which is true by the bounds I've given.

Comment: @user715522: Did you check [this](http://oeis.org/A179119)? BTW, here's my [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) session:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{foo(n)=sumdiv(n,d,if(d==1,0,moebius(n/d)*d*(-1)^d))}
\\\texttt{logzeta(a,n)={my(r=zeta(n));forprime(p=2,a,r*=1-p^(-n));return(log(r))}}
\\\texttt{goo(a)={my(r=suminf(n=2,foo(n)/n*logzeta(a,n)));forprime(p=2,a,r+=1/p/(p+1));return(r)}}
\\\texttt{\p100}
\\\texttt{goo(50)}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Oh, you are right. I calculated those bounds for half the sum actually, which was my original problem. I'll edit that

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an answer, but.

If we consider
$$
\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p(p + 1)}
= 
\sum_{p \leq x} \left( \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{p + 1} \right),
$$
the question amounts to determining the constant $A$
appearing in the asymptotic formula of the form
$\sim \log \log x  + A + o(1)$ for the sum
$$
\sum_{p \leq x}\frac{1}{p + 1}.
$$

I don't think A takes an easy form.